# Uncaught Error occured - 'mat-icon' is not a known element:

Tags: angular

The error occurred while running.

```
Unexpected value 'MatIconRegistry' imported by the module 'AppModule'. 
Please add a @NgModule annotation
```

How to solve this error. I added the "@angular/material" in app.module.ts. Still, it's thrown an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import MatIconModule in your app.module.ts file as below -

```
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';


imports: [
   // Your other imports
   MatIconModule
],
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I import the needed Module in app.module.ts. Still thrown an error. I used the MatIconRegistry in the specific component, it has thrown an error like this  " Unexpected value 'MatIconRegistry' imported by the module 'AppModule'. 
Please add a NgModule annotation"

Comment: have you imported all modules from @angular/material?

Comment: Yes, I imported all modules @angular/material

Comment: have you imported this import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material/icon';

Comment: Yes, I imported    "import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';"

Then I mentioned MatIconRegistry like this in constructor

constructor(private router: Router, iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer,){
iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('company-heroic', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/images/company-heroic.svg'));
}